# Как действиями в popup расширения влиять на текущую вкладку или определённую страницу

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Сразу скажу что я не программист, просто по фану иногда пишу код.
Суть вопроса в следующем. Пишу расширение для браузера. Нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки в popup выполнялся скрипт на определённой(ых) странице. Если я правильно понимаю это нужно делать через context-script, но не знаю как.
Прошу навести меня на ресурсы для изучения необходимой информации.
Заранее благодарю за внимание.

Comment: через [executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/scripting)